# Invalid syntax in python 3 (elif statement)

Tags: python

When I try to run this code, I get an error called 'Invalid Syntax' on the first elif statement. I've been researching and haven't been able to find a reason why it won't work.
I'm pretty sure I am using the latest version of python (3.8.2).

```
def likes(names):
  if (len(names) >= 4):
      print("{}, {} and {} others like this".format(names[0], names[1], len(names)-2)
  elif (len(names) == 3):
      print("{}, {} and {} like this".format(names[0], names[1], names[2])
  elif (len(names) == 2):
      print("{} and {} like this".format(names[0], names[1])
  elif (len(names) == 1):
      print("{} likes this".format(names[0])
  else:
      print("no one likes this")
```

Comment: Simple typo, your first `print` statement has mismatched parentheses. In fact, most of them seem to have this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing matching parentheses for all of your `print` statements except for the last, it should be:

```
def likes(names):
  if (len(names) >= 4):
      print("{}, {} and {} others like this".format(names[0], names[1], len(names)-2))
  elif (len(names) == 3):
      print("{}, {} and {} like this".format(names[0], names[1], names[2]))
  elif (len(names) == 2):
      print("{} and {} like this".format(names[0], names[1]))
  elif (len(names) == 1):
      print("{} likes this".format(names[0]))
  else:
      print("no one likes this")
```

Comment: damn, How did I not realize that? Now the code is functioning properly.

Comment: @003264_ haha it happens